# Entity Framework - Where is my Object Context?

Tags: entity-framework, objectcontext

Ok, I'm obviously missing something very basic.  I'm very new to Entity Framework.

I want to call stored procedures without importing them, so I was planning on using ExecuteStoreQuery().  According to the documentation, ExecuteStoreQuery is a method of ObjectContext.  But, I have no idea where to get my ObjectContext.

I generated my entites using Database First.  So far, I have been accessing my entities something like this:

```
var db = new MyEntities();

PRODUCT p = db.PRODUCTS.First(a => a.PRODUCTSKEY == thekey);
```

But I can't call db.ExecuteStoreQuery, becase db isn't an ObjectContext.

I've googled how to get ObjectContext from an entity.  I find some answers, but they're all flagged with cautions, saying that it's a workaround, and only to use it if you have no other option.  Ok, so what is the RIGHT way?

All examples that I've found for using ExecuteStoreQuery assume that you already have your ObjectContext.  Not very helpful.

I found one website that stated that the ObjectContext is "automatically generated" by Entity Framework.  If that's the case, then where is it?

I'm obviously missing something very simple here.  This can't be that difficult.

Comment: `db.ExecuteStoreQuery()`?

Comment: @jrummell No. db is a DbContext instance which has no such method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To get to the ObjectContext of your DbContext, all you'd need to do is the following:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)myDbContextObject).ObjectContext;
```

Answer (score 13):

`ObjectContext` was replaced by `DbContext` in Entity Framework 4.1. Actually `DbContext` is an adapter (wrapper) over `ObjectContext`. If you need to get `ObjectContext` you can cast your `DbContext` instance to `IObjectContextAdapter` interface (it is implemented explicitly) and wrapped `ObjectContext` instance will be available:

```
ObjectContext context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
```

BTW I think you are looking for [`db.Database.SqlQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Actually the replacement happened in EF 4.1, with the introduction of Code-First, see this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In Your case MyEntities is your ObjectContext.

Technically it is auto-generated class by EntityFramework that inherits from ObjectContext class.

Comment: Ok, if I try: MyEntities.ExecuteStoreQuery(MyQuery), the compiler says that MyEntities "does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteStoreQuery'"

Comment: Others are correct, depends which version of EF you are using, for EF4 and earlier, you should be able to follow steps here: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/03/06/mapping-stored-procedures-to-objectcontext-methods.aspx